# Desacoplar completamente una librería en la inyección de dependencias de .net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, ddd

Pretendo usar la inversion de control en ".Net Core" con el inyector de dependencias "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection", pero quiero conseguir desacoplar completamente una libería de la otra, tal y como lo estoy usando actualmente es algo así:

```
/// <summary>
/// Inyección de dependencias del proyecto de Dominio
/// </summary>
public static class DependenciasDominio
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Método de extensión que realiza la inyección de dependencias del proyecto de Dominio
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services">Collección de servicios para usar la inyección de dependencias</param>
    /// <returns>Collección de servicios</returns>
    public static IServiceCollection AgregarDependenciasDominio(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Se instancia una única vez mediante Singleton
        services.AddSingleton<IDireccionesRepository, DireccionesRepository>();

        return services;
    }
}
```

Donde "IDireccionesRepository" es una interfaz declarada en el proyecto donde se está el inyector de dependencias, y "DireccionesRepository" está en otro proyecto desde el que se hace las llamadas a base de datos.

Tal y como está actualmente requiere que el proyecto de datos esté referenciado en el proyecto de dominio para poder encontrar la clase "DireccionesRepository", pero me gustaría aplicar el principio de desarrollo de DDD donde el proyecto de dominio está desacoplado por completo del resto de proyectos, no hay referencias al resto de capas, por tanto sería cargar el proyecto de datos de forma dinámica según un fichero de configuración.

Esto con otros inyectores de dependencias en .Net Framework se podía hacer, como por ejemplo con Unity y el fichero de configuración app.config/web.config, tal y como se indica en [esta web](https://devonblog.com/software-development/configure-unity-container-config-file/). ¿Qué ventaja tiene esto?, por ejemplo, tengo un cliente el cual dependiendo donde le instale la aplicación va a acceder a una base de datos SqlServer, Oracle o MySql, mediante el fichero de configuración se puede indicar qué tipo de base de datos va a utilizar sin tener que generar 3 compilaciones distintas en el proyecto de negocio, y si la base de datos cambia tan sólo hay que detener el servicio cambiar el fichero de configuración y listo, sin tener que recompilar nada.

El caso es que he intentado cargar dinámicamente la librería de la siguiente forma:

```
string directorioEnsamblado = Path.GetDirectoryName(rutaEnsamblado) + "\\";
AssemblyLoader assemblyLoader = new AssemblyLoader(directorioEnsamblado);
Assembly ensamblado = assemblyLoader.Load(rutaEnsamblado);
Type tipoImplementador = ensamblado.DefinedTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.FullName == tipoClase);
```

Que efectivamente me resuelve el tipo de forma correcta, sólo que al invocar a algún método de esta clase me da error porque no encuentra el resto de librerías que necesita para poder funcionar, como por ejemplo "System.Linq".

Estoy apunto de resolverlo, gracias a los comentarios de [Andres Lozada Mosto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/127525/andres-lozada-mosto), pero cualquier aportación será bienvenida y me parece un tema lo bastante interesante y desconocido como para compartirlo aquí.

Un saludo.

Comment: porque la interfaz la defines en el proyecto web? eso no esta correcto. La interface IAlgo deberia estar en un proyecto separado, el cual referencies en el proyecto web

Comment: Leandro la interfaz está en este caso en el proyecto web porque lo que se pretende es no tener una referencia a otro proyecto, por tanto el "contrato" está en el proyecto web y el constructor está en el otro proyecto, por así decirlo es un acercamiento a la implementación del patrón repositorio explicado en el libro DDD de Cesar de la Torre, terminas desacoplando por completo las "capas"... no se si me explico

Comment: pero entonces desde el proyecto que implementa la interfaz debe referencia al proyecto web (donde esta la interfaz)? si es asi entonces es una pesima idea, totalmene incorrecta. No se que has entendido del libro que mencionas, pero no es correcto lo que estas desarrollando.

Comment: no entendi a que te refieres con "constructor", imagino sera la implementacion de la interfaz de repository, pero si esta en otro proyecto entonces esta refrencia al proyecto web, eso esta mal

Comment: Entiendo lo que intentas hacer, pero creo que no es lo mejor... Con Net Core se pueden seguir cargando las dlls de forma dinámica como indicas que lo hacías con Unity
Te dejo este links: [https://shazwazza.com/post/custom-assembly-loading-with-aspnet-core/](https://shazwazza.com/post/custom-assembly-loading-with-aspnet-core/) que lo integra con IOC de Net Core y este otro que explica mas en detalle el tema de una arquitectura de plugins con Net Core [https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2018/07/25/netcore-plugins/](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2018/07/25/netcore-plugins/) Como podes ver en el primer

Comment: Hola Leandro, lo que se intenta con Unity mediante la configuración en el fichero XML es precisamente poder resolver las interfaces mediante constructores en librerías no referenciadas, de esta manera quedan completamente desacopladas y en el caso de tener que cambiar una librería no obligarte a realizar la compilación de la otra. Si nos ponemos en serio a implementar DDD desde luego referenciar hacia el proyecto web obviamente es una pésima idea, pero mi intención no era ponerme a hablar sobre DDD sino de como implementar IoC con las librerías completamente desacopladas

Comment: Efectivamente has captado lo que quiero hacer, echaré un vistazo un poco más profundo estos días a los enlaces y con lo que sea comento el resultado. La verdad es que la arquitectura de plugins con Net Core la desconozco y probablemente ahí que quiera insistir. La posibilidad de poder cambiar una librería sin tener que volver a compilar otra creo que es una buena idea, ya veremos. Gracias por las referencias.

Comment: pero te pusiste analizar cual es la ventaja de esto que quieres conseguir? digo si es cuestion de actualizar la implementaicon en caliente, probaste hacer? no sera que aunque actualices la libreria el sitio se reinicia de todas formas. Lo que planteas no tiene nada que ver con DDD, esta es una forma de diseño del dominio, inyectar dependencias es lo de menos.

Comment: Leandro imagínate una aplicación de escritorio de asistencia sanitaria, la cual depende de los servicios de terceros como Asisa, Sanitas, Adeslas, etc. Bien pues se llega a un acuerdo con ellos para que aporten sus propias librerías pero cumpliendo con las mismas interfaces, implementando por tanto una inyección de dependencias. Ahora bien queremos que al actualizar la aplicación el paquete de distribución sea lo más pequeño posible, desacoplando por completo estas librerías sería posible. Es sólo un ejemplo, con esto quiero decir que aunque tú no le veas utilidad no significa que no la tenga

Comment: Por desgracia la solución que me has indicado es para .net Core 1 y ya no es válida, seguiré investigando a ver si lo consigo, pero gracias porque al menos se que en un momento dado se ha podido hacer

Comment: ok lo que planteas lo entiendo, pero podrias poner las dll que te proporcionan sin necesidad que sea tan dinamicos su incorporacion, las agregas compilas y deployas nueamente. en realidad hay otra tecnica que se usa para estos casos y es una arquitectura de micro servicios, si tienes dependencia a funcionalidad de terceros lo expones como un servicio separado que tu consumes, no lo itegras a ti desarrollo, lo consumes

Comment: igual sigo planteando que las interfaces las estas definiendo en el lugar incorrectos, debes separarlas en un proyecto aparte, NUNCA van en el proyecto web. Una libreria extrna no deberia referencia al proyecto web.

Comment: Leandro tu ganas, he cambiado el planteamiento de la pregunta, ya está la interfaz donde debe, ahora a ver si hay suerte y sabes la respuesta, sino la sabes y te quedas con ganas de seguir discutiendo sobre DDD, microservicios e interfaces mejor quedamos y lo hacemos con unas cervecitas

Comment: No solo para net core 1....La idea es la misma en net core 2.x. Por favor la prox detalla para que version es para darte un mejor apoyo. Revisa este link [http://mypublicnotepad.com/2018/03/31/dynamic-assembly-loading-in-aspnet-core/] Por otro lado, el 2do link de mi comentario anterior depende de NetStarndard y no de Net Core por lo que se puede utilizar para NetCore 1.x y 2.x. Intenta con los ejemplos de estos links y cualquier bloqueo que tengas publicalo por acá para darte una mano

Comment: Hola Andrés, lo primero, no se quién te ha dado un negativo pero te aseguro que no he sido yo, de hecho tu segundo link en la respuesta parece ser justo lo que busco, pero todavía no he podido probarlo bien y por eso no la he dado todavía como la definitiva. No sabía que podía diferir entre la versión 1.x y la 2.x, pero está claro que la próxima no me pasa y lo pongo. Estoy muy cerca de resolverlo, así que te agradezco tu contestación y espero poner tu respuesta como la buena, intentaré de todas formas compartir el código para dejarlo fino.

Comment: hola, no te preocupes por el voto negativo, es anónimo y pudo ser cualquiera o incluso por error. Si, hubieron cambios grandes entre 1.x y 2.x en algunos aspectos del framework por eso siempre es conveniente aclararlo, incluso entre 2.0 y 2.1 hay tb cambios sustanciales en algunas cosas. Espero q te sirva la info q te pase, la ultima vez q tuve q hacer algo asi fue hace 8 años y con net 4.5... muy diferente a como es netcore ahora. saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues al final es mucho más sencillo de lo que esperaba. Estaba utilizando "Assembly.Load" ya que había leido que cuando la librería estaba en la misma carpeta "bin" que el ensamblado era suficiente, pero parece que para ".Net Core" no, y por tanto cuando he usado "Assembly.LoadFrom" es cuando lo he conseguido.

Cabe destacar que me habían recomendado el uso del paquete NuGet "McMaster.NETCore.Plugins", y que efectivamente funciona, pero viendo que directamente se puede usar con "Assembly" me ha parecido mejor al no depender de librerías de terceros.

Detallo el proceso.

Lo primero es crear un fichero de configuración (JSON) con las dependencias en el proyecto de negocio. Se le especifica la interfaz a implementar (la cual presupone que está en la misma librería que la invoca, para el ejemplo creo que es más que suficiente), la ruta de la librería dll que la va a implementar, la clase que la implementa, y el tipo de registro (Singleton, Transient, Scoped):

```
[
  {
    "ContratoEspacioNombres": "PoCInyeccionDesacoplada.Dominio.Contratos.IDireccionesRepository",
    "ImplementadorRutaEnsamblado": "PoCInyeccionDesacoplada.InfraestructuraDatos.dll",
    "ImplementadorEspacioNombresClase": "PoCInyeccionDesacoplada.InfraestructuraDatos.Repositorios.DireccionesRepository",
    "TipoRegistro": "Singleton"
  },
  {
    "ContratoEspacioNombres": "PoCInyeccionDesacoplada.Dominio.Contratos.IInicializacionRepository",
    "ImplementadorRutaEnsamblado": "PoCInyeccionDesacoplada.InfraestructuraDatos.dll",
    "ImplementadorEspacioNombresClase": "PoCInyeccionDesacoplada.InfraestructuraDatos.Repositorios.InicializacionRepository",
    "TipoRegistro": "Transient"
  }
]
```

Por otro lado se extiende "IServiceCollection" para agregar las dependencias del proyecto de negocio, tomando los datos de registro de la inyección de dependencias del fichero de configuración explicado anteriormente:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using PoCInyeccionDesacoplada.Dominio.Servicios.IoC;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace PoCInyeccionDesacoplada.Dominio.Servicios
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Inyección de dependencias del proyecto de Dominio
    /// </summary>
    public static class DependenciasDominio
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Método de extensión que realiza la inyección de dependencias del proyecto de Dominio
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="services">Collección de servicios para usar la inyección de dependencias</param>
        /// <returns>Collección de servicios</returns>
        public static IServiceCollection AgregarDependenciasDominio(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var localPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
            var ficheroConfiguracionDependencias = Path.Combine(localPath, "ConfiguracionDependencias.json");

            // Comprueba la existencia del fichero
            if (File.Exists(ficheroConfiguracionDependencias))
            {
                string strConfiguracionDependencias = File.ReadAllText(ficheroConfiguracionDependencias);
                // Comprueba que no viene vacío
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strConfiguracionDependencias))
                {
                    var configuracionDependencias = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ConfiguracionDependencia>>(strConfiguracionDependencias);
                    // Comprueba que tiene configuraciones
                    if (configuracionDependencias != null && configuracionDependencias.Any())
                    {
                        foreach (var configuracionDependencia in configuracionDependencias)
                        {
                            Type tipoContrato = Type.GetType(configuracionDependencia.ContratoEspacioNombres);
                            // Comprueba que el tipo del contrato está bien definido
                            if (tipoContrato != null)
                            {
                                Type tipoDependencia = null;

                                // Comprueba si la ruta de la dll es absoluta o relativa
                                if (File.Exists(configuracionDependencia.ImplementadorRutaEnsamblado))
                                {
                                    // Ruta absoluta
                                    tipoDependencia = GestorDependencias.ObtenerTipoDependencia(tipoContrato, configuracionDependencia.ImplementadorRutaEnsamblado, configuracionDependencia.ImplementadorEspacioNombresClase);
                                }
                                else if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(localPath, configuracionDependencia.ImplementadorRutaEnsamblado)))
                                {
                                    // Ruta relativa
                                    tipoDependencia = GestorDependencias.ObtenerTipoDependencia(tipoContrato, Path.Combine(localPath, configuracionDependencia.ImplementadorRutaEnsamblado), configuracionDependencia.ImplementadorEspacioNombresClase);
                                }

                                // Si encuentra el tipo de dependencia lo añade
                                if (tipoDependencia != null)
                                {
                                    // Por defecto es Singleton
                                    switch (configuracionDependencia.TipoRegistro)
                                    {
                                        case OpcionRegistro.Scope:
                                            services.AddScoped(tipoContrato, tipoDependencia);
                                            break;
                                        case OpcionRegistro.Transient:
                                            services.AddTransient(tipoContrato, tipoDependencia);
                                            break;
                                        default:
                                            services.AddSingleton(tipoContrato, tipoDependencia);
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return services;
        }
    }
}
```

Y por último se llama a la carga del ensamblado para que resuelva el tipo implementador para la interfaz:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;

namespace PoCInyeccionDesacoplada.Dominio.Servicios.IoC
{
    public static class GestorDependencias
    {
        public static Type ObtenerTipoDependencia(Type tipoContrato, string rutaEnsamblado, string tipoClase)
        {
            // Se debe hacer con LoadFrom para que cargue las librerías dependientes
            Assembly ensamblado = Assembly.LoadFrom(rutaEnsamblado);

            return ensamblado.DefinedTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.FullName == tipoClase);
        }
    }
}
```

Por tanto luego desde el proyecto API se invoca al método de extensión:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    // Gestión de inyección de dependencias
    services.AgregarDependenciasApi()
        .AgregarDependenciasDominio();
}
```

Espero que la solución quede clara, pero sino contádmelo y lo edito para que sea lo más legible posible.

Saludos.